# Magento product display text "array" instead of multiple values

Tags: arrays, magento, custom-attributes

On my Magento product page; when a product has multiple values for one custom attribute; instead of displaying the values it displays the text "array". It works fine with one value.
Thanks,
-Sam

Comment: You have to iterate through the values and display them individually. Since you didn't give much information, that's all I can offer sorry.

Comment: Hi Zachary, I have the following code in my product's view.phtml file:   `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('metal') ?>`  How would I iterate through them to get them all to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on Magento forums and it seems to work:
` getData('attribute_name')): ?>

getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) ?>

`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<?php
    foreach($_product->getMetal() as $name => $value): ?>
<?php echo $name;?> = <?php echo $value;?>
<?php
    endforeach; ?>
```

Magento takes advantage of PHP's magic getter/setter functionality (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

You can do a `vardump($_product)` to see the available attributes (they are stored in the _data array in the product). Then to retrieve one of them, you just remove the underscores and change the first letter of each word to uppercase.

**EDIT:**

If the above code doesn't output values, you can do this (which will tell you how to get to the value):

```
<?php
    foreach($_product->getMetal() as $attribute): ?>
<?php var_dump($attribute); ?>
<?php
    endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours; and now it displays not values.

Comment: Only Problem is I can't figure out how to separate values with br or bullet points.